# Tracking first click only in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have tracking on my button that tracks every time it has been clicked. How do I get this to work so that the tracking call gets called only on the first click and no other clicks. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

.TS File

```
public reset(): void {
   this.myTrackingService.submitAnalyticsCall(new MyAnalyticsModel(
        APP-CONSTANTS.destination.myaccount));
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="showMyFilter" class="my-filter--container">
<my-filter(selectReset)="onReset()"></my-filter></div>
```

Comment: You can keep track of the button in a service. Add a property to the service like `clickedTrackingElements = new Set<HTMLElement>();` make sure it's not in the set before performing the API call and then add it to the set. There are other approaches of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to track the clicks in a local variable:

```js
public reset(): void {
   let clicked = false;
   if(!clicked) {
      this.myTrackingService.submitAnalyticsCall(new MyAnalyticsModel(
        APP-CONSTANTS.destination.myaccount));
      clicked = true;
   }
}
```

A more elaborate way would be to do that with RxJs by creating a stream/observable from a click event and then using the `take(1)` operator, but that might be an overkill for this purpose.

In the template, add a reference, and remove `click()`:

```html
<my-filter #trackOne></my-filter>
<my-filter #trackTwo></my-filter>
```

In the class (has to be in `AfterViewInit()`, and not in `OnInit()`):

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('trackOne', {read: ElementRef}) trackButtonOne: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('trackTwo', {read: ElementRef}) trackButtonTwo: ElementRef;
  buttonClicksOne$: Observable<Event>;
  buttonClicksTwo$: Observable<Event>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.buttonClicksOne$ = fromEvent(this.trackButtonOne.nativeElement,'click');
    this.buttonClicksOne$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {this.myTrackingService.submitAnalyticsCall(new MyAnalyticsModel(
        APP-CONSTANTS.destination.myaccount));});

    this.buttonClicksTwo$ = fromEvent(this.trackButtonTwo.nativeElement,'click');
    this.buttonClicksTwo$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {this.myTrackingService.submitAnalyticsCall(new MyAnalyticsModel(
        APP-CONSTANTS.destination.myaccount));});
  }
}
```

To make this work for two separate components, so it tracks each component click once, you can add individual references in the template (e.g. `#trackOne` & `#trackTwo`, create two properties and event listeners in the class for each `ViewChild()` like shown above.

Comment: This worked. I appreciate it. If you don't mind could you show me how the more elaborate way works?

Comment: Is there any way to force this to happen when page refreshes rather than component. I have buttons in two different components. This seems to work based on which component i clicked.

Comment: @rdopler Updated the example with how to do this with RxJs. For your second question, not sure I understood completely, but if not, please post a separate question if your original question has been answered, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with your method being called again after a refresh or if you open a new tab then you can create a flag for this.

```
public clicked: boolean = false;

public reset(): void {
    if (!this.clicked) {
        this.myTrackingService.submitAnalyticsCall(new MyAnalyticsModel(
             APP-CONSTANTS.destination.myaccount));
        this.clicked = true;
    }
}
```